# Spring bean initialization - Clojure

Tags: spring, clojure

I have a clojure class which I initialize using spring bean initialization.

My setter method is as follows

> (defn -setCompanyName [currency]   (println (str "company : " company)))

Bean initialization is as follows

> ```
> <bean id="company" class="test.Company"
>         p:companyName="orce"/>
> ```

I'm getting following error.

> Invalid property 'companyName' of bean class [test.Company]: Bean property
>   'companyName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does
>   the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Does anyone knows the root cause for this issue.

Regards
Isuru.

Answer (score 3):

There are several possible causes for this particular issue, so without all your code it is difficult to say what is failing.

Here is the code that works for me:

```
(ns test)

(gen-class
   :main false
   :name test.Company
   :methods [[setCompanyName [String] void]])

(defn -setCompanyName [this company] (println (str "company : " company)))
```

Notes:

- you do **not** need any getter
- the signature of the method is specified in the :methods vector.
- your functions should have an additional "this" parameter
- gen-class macro generates a class based on the parameters of the macro, so it does **not** look at the -setCompanyName function definition at all.

I find very useful the javap command to see what gen-class is generating:

```
javap.exe -classpath classes/ test.Company
public class test.Company extends java.lang.Object{
    public static {};
    public test.Company();
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public java.lang.Object clone();
    public int hashCode();
    public void setCompanyName(java.lang.String);
}
```

I will also recommend you to look at the second example on http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/gen-class to see how to manage state.

Comment: are you sure the getter is not needed?  the error explicitly mentions it and, in my experience, java bean related code often requires it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I tested the code before posting the response, so yes, I am sure that you don't need a getter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need another function parameter? The first acts as a 'this' pointer. I can't test this right now as I'm on my phone.